# Can two USB to Ethernet adapters be used as a USB2 extension?

Tags: usb, ethernet, adapter, rj-45

I want to use RJ45 type of cables to make a 10m USB2 extension.
Is it possible using two USB to Ethernet adapters (even without drivers so they act as USB to RJ45 adapters, not as Ethernet ports).
If not, I only found USB1 to RJ45/CAT5 and very (compared to HDMI equivalents) expensive USB2 to RJ45/CAT5.

Here's a list of those cables by one manufacturer: http://www.lindy.co.uk/usb-firewire/usb-converters-extenders/

Comment: Your title proposes a question that is different than the body. Which are you looking to answer?

Comment: I don't see the difference.

Comment: I was horribly confused at first too. But "USB to Ethernet adapter" could be parsed two different ways: "(USB to Ethernet) adapter" or "USB to (Ethernet adapter)"

Comment: You might want to add a picture to your question to help avoid the "USB extender" vs "USB ethernet" confusion.

Comment: The question is clear, if you don't know what a USB to Ethernet adapter is, do some research.

Answer (score 3):

**Physical Considerations**
An Ethernet cable has 8 wires
A Usb cable has 4 wires.

Ethernet cables can support up to 25 watts with 802.3 [Power over Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)
USB supports a maximum of [10 watts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB).

**Example**
Take this product from newegg
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2970S53111

It supports Cat 5e over ethernet for up to 50M (150 feet).

It would be possible to splice a cable in two and run two usb

In my work I have seen two network connections running over 1 cable (because cat 5 only needs 4 wires). I have also seen [hdmi over a network cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FYK392) (using all 8 wires)

**Reasons it might not work**
Usb devices are more susceptible to voltage irregularities than network devices are.
The cross over might cause too much interference.

If you have not run the network cable yet, I would highly recommend doing it right, and getting [siamese cat5e](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0043JPM8O)

http://www.churchvideo.co.uk/misc/howto-two-network-connections-on-a-single-cat5-cable_139.html

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0043JPM8O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0043JPM8O)

Comment: I already use the HDMI over 2 RJ45 cables solution that you mentioned and I spotted a similar USB solution using RJ12 cables but couldn't find it again - RJ45 adapters seem more common so I inquired about those. The Baaqii A204 is exactly what I would need, if it delivers more than 100mA (cause that's what active USB extensions deliver and it's not enough). I'm also wondering if I could use any 2 identical adapters, or does the Baaqii A204 have something special.

Comment: Apparently the Baaqii A204 is only USB1 and very _bad_ Chinese quality. Do you know any affordable USB2 to RJ45/CAT5 adapter ?

Comment: I don't, however there are quite a few listed on newegg that have various reviews. I would guess that you will get unexpected results if you mix adapters, but I have never tried it.

Comment: I found out that USB2 to RJ45 adapters that work as USB extension are so expensive than it's better to buy USB cables.  I also tried using 2 USB3 internet adapters but while without drivers one is recognized as a USB device the device connected at the end is not powered even if the receiver adapter is connected to a hub.

Answer (score 2):

> Can two USB to Ethernet adapters be used as a USB extension cable?

A USB ethernet adapter could mean one of two things:

1) a smart dongle that lets you plug in and get networking packets (like on the side of your laptop)

2) a dumb dongle that just passes thru USB

> If one USB to RJ45 adapter is used as emitter and the other as receiver, what would be the signal's maximum range (meters) and intensity (mA) ?

If you have 2 smart dongles, you could use something like [USBIP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) to have a "remote USB" between two computers to share a USB peripheral from one computer to another. Cables are limited to 185 meters, mainly because of  possible collisions (computers talk so fast that the speed of light starts to matter.)

If you have 2 dumb dongles, it acts like a USB extension cable. The distance will depend on the dongle, but could be longer in theory because only one side is talking at a time. With longer cable lengths, it might only work with some devices because of unexpected latency.

Comment: One doesn't need an adapter if one doesn't uses wires. It's pretty clear what a USB to Ethernet/RJ45 adapter is http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=azs_osd_firefox?tag=amznsearchff-20&link_code=qs&index=aps&field-keywords=usb+to+ethernet+adapter